# Does an RPM require a compile phase?

Tags: linux, rpm

I want to build an RPM of OpenCV for a distribution of Oracle Linux. I have been reading various guides to making an RPM (see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rpm1/), and from [Fedora's documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-creating-rpms.html#id589414), I read the following:

> The RPM system will automate the steps to create an application, as
>   long as you configure the RPM with the proper steps, such as which
>   make targets to run. Unfortunately, configuring the proper steps is
>   not always easy. So before trying to make an RPM, you need to figure
>   out how to build the application or library you plan to package into
>   an RPM. Once you have figured out how to build the application or
>   library, you can set up a reproducible build. The RPM system can then
>   automate this build.

From this I gather that RPM doesn't install prebuilt libraries and binaries, but builds them from source. However, my experience tells me that when I download packages that I am just installing prebuilt binaries. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different things. You can package an application using

```
rpm system using a spec file
```

The spec file is the recipe for creating your application. Once you have a spec file. You can use it generate a src rpm or binary rpm. Binary rpm is the rpm that you were referring.

The spec file specifies how to build/package your rpm. We use rpmbuild command to build the rpm.

Now you can use rpm command to install/uninstall/upgrade the rpm package.

Please don't be confused between rpm, the package AND rpm system, the engine responsible for building the rpm

Comment: So the long and short, you use rpmbuild to make an RPM which can be a self contained combination of libraries and binaries which the user can then install onto their system using rpm/yum. Correct?

Comment: What you call rpm system is called rpmbuild. There is no confusion there.

Comment: To expand on this, an rpm can contain anything you need. I package configuration for our monitoring system in rpms. The repository where we keep those rpms/srpms is also a configuration version control of sorts

Comment: Yes, Reading the question, I felt like he is not clear about the distinction